# Custom Javascript for referrer URL in GTM using custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

GA and GTM noob here.

Need to setup a custom Javascript Variable in GTM to check the referrer URL and set up a custom dimension. I would also need to set up a cookie with some specifications.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

For the referrer you do not need a custom variable - referrer is a built-in, you just need to enable it.

If you insist on using a custom JavaScript it would look something like

```
function() {
    return document.referrer; 
}
```

I do not see any advantage over the built-in.

GTM does not usually set cookies, so you need your own function for this. I suggest you use a Custom Javascript to return a function that sets cookies, and use that function in Custom HTML tags.

Variable setCookie ([setCookie function from here](https://plainjs.com/javascript/utilities/set-cookie-get-cookie-and-delete-cookie-5/))

```
function() {
    return setCookie(name, value, days) {
        var d = new Date;
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * days);
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";path=/;expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    }
}
```

Then you can use this in a Custom HTML tag

```
{{setCookie}}("myCookie","myValue",7);
```

Comment: That was very helpful. 



This might be a stupid question, but can the function returning the referrer and setting cookies be combined? What I am trying to do is set up tracking for a partner referral and also enable tracking of returning users (when the user does not come from the partner website) using the cookie.

Comment: Technically yes, but you shouldn't do operations with side effects (like setting cookies) in a variable (variables might be evaluated a couple of times per page. You might decide that is not a problem for your use case). You can reference variables within other variables, so you can just plug the built-in referrer into the setCookie function.